# How to add a duration which can be in any time unit to a given timestamp in jq?

Tags: json, jq

```
{
    "applicationDuration": {
    "duration": 4,
    "unit": "DAY"
    },
    "startTime": {
    "long": 1539196595567
    }
}
```

I am writing a jq script which takes a json with the fields similar to above. The goal is to increment the `startTime` by adding the given `duration`. `startTime` is in milliseconds whereas `duration` can be any time unit (ms, sec, min, hr, day, week, month, year) which is provided with `unit`. Is it possible to do something like below?

```
startTime = ToMillis(FOO(startTime) + BAR(duration, unit))
```

Similar to java`s: https://www.javacodex.com/Date-and-Time/Add-Time-To-A-Timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that takes into account leap years:

```
# Input and output are both in milliseconds since the epoch; 
# the output time is later than the input time by $n units, where
# the units are determined by $unit, one of the strings in `dict`.
def later($n; $unit):
  def dict: { YEAR:0, MONTH:1, DAY:2, HOUR:3, MINUTE:4, SECOND:5, MIN:4, SEC:5};
  gmtime
  | .[dict[$unit]] += $n
  | mktime ;
```

### Testing

```
("2019-01-24" | strptime("%Y-%m-%d") | mktime)
| (later(2; "YEAR"), later(731; "DAY"))
| strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Output is as expected (as 2020 is a leap year):

```
"2021-01-24"
"2021-01-24"
```

---

<sub>keyword: addTime</sub>

Comment: Hey peak, This looks like very elegant solution. Thank you very much! I will give it a shot :)